# ListView is not showing response fetched using Retrofit - Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am making a GET request to an API using Retrofit, my app is successfully making the request as I am getting the response but I want to show that response into a ListView but the response is not displaying in the ListView. My code is as follows :

MainActivity.java :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView myListView;

List<Todo> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Todo>();

ArrayAdapter<Todo> myArrayAdapter;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Todo>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , myArrayList);
    myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
}

public void getTodo(View view) {
    Call<List<Todo>> getCall = apiInterface.getTodo();
    getCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Todo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Todo>> call, Response<List<Todo>> response) {
            Log.e(TAG , "onResponse : "+response.body());
            myArrayList = response.body();

            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
//                Log.e(TAG , "arraylist : "+myArrayList);  // This Log is printing data in arraylist which means myArrayList contains data.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Todo>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG , "onFailure : "+t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    });

}
}
```

My Todo.java class is as follows :

Todo.java :-

```
public class Todo {

private String _id;
private String name;
private String added_date;
private int __v;

public Todo(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Todo{" +
            "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", added_date='" + added_date + '\'' +
            ", __v=" + __v +
            '}';
}
}
```

Sample response is as follows :

```
onResponse : [Todo{_id='5f9140a5827320001796726f', name='Attend Meeting', 
added_date='2021-04-30T08:19:49.400Z', __v=0}]
```

Comment: your log is correctly printing the log ?

Comment: yes it is printing correctly.

Comment: myArrayList = response.body(); replace this to this myArrayList.add(response.body());

Comment: error: no suitable method found for add(List<Todo>)
                myArrayList.add(response.body());

Comment: I am getting this error by adding your line.

Comment: try this myArrayList.addAll(response.body());, add will not work as it need to be an Todo object

Comment: yes and thank you now I am getting data in my list view but each data is in JSON form. how to fix that ?

Comment: change your toString to just name

Comment: if it helped can you please upvote my answer and accept it. It will help someone in future

Comment: @stackoverflow9949

Answer (score 0):

change `myArrayList = response.body();` to `myArrayList.addAll(response.body());`

and also update your toString to something like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

That way your ListView looks neat rather than a big confusing String.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you using data that you received anywhere. You pass the empty list `myArrayList` to your adapter constructor.

`myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Todo>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , myArrayList);`

And when you get the data from the API, you just assign it to the list, and you don't pass it to the adapter. Move this part of the code

`myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Todo>(MainActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , myArrayList); myListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);`

To the on response method, after you assign data to the list, or add method to the adapter, which can update the list, and after that call  `myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`